# classify objects into binned categories

Tags: classification

I need to generate a model which is able to classify objects into binned categories. These categories are related to each other as they are bins of a continuous variable. Let's say predicted value included in the following intervals: < 50, 50-75, 75-100, 100-125, 125-150, > 150. This depend on 2 reasons: (1) the read out of data used to build the model has a similar format, especially at the extremes < 50 and > 150; (2) I've tried already MLR just to model the 50-150 area but it was quite unsuccessful

Comment: Predict first, then bin is my advice in broad terms given a need to do this (which in turn I don't understand). Specifically I don't think you are giving enough information on precisely what you are doing to allow  more detailed, or even different, advice.

Comment: Sorry for no explaining with more details. My exp. data which I use for the training set comes in this format: a value if they are included in the 50-150 interval or just < 50 or > 150 is they are out of the interval. A MLR will work only in the 50-150 interval. I was trying to use a single models if possible rather than a couple or more. If prediction could be made as bins (rather than actual values) it would be fine anyway (if this means I can include also < 50 and > 150 in my training set).

Comment: Thanks for the details. This sounds to me like a truncated regression. Fitting separate models is indeed not at all the thing to do. It's a standard econometrics problem, for example. Even if you don't use Stata, http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rtruncreg.pdf indicates one way to move and some literature references.